Stacked coefficient plot + formatting
I have the following data and coefficient plot:
plot <- structure(list(country_name = c("Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", "Country 4", 
                                "Average", "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", 
                                "Country 4", "Average", "Country 1", "Country 2", 
                                "Country 3", "Country 4", "Average", 
                                "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", "Country 4", "Average"
), estimate = c(0.0775106482281853, 0.17632671064236, 0.0013288864931758, 
                0.126302702621548, 0.125235423445702, 0.0386537980255854, -0.0075361625768661, 
                0.0470832000160646, 0.0064181611108639, 0.0138120446354151, 0.0101733983229246, 
                0.0041374966930428, 0.115121613729783, 0.0751024522805836, 0.0194394793361425, 
                -0.0279320299938204, 0.194391655386469, 0.0011704593928677, 0.0289201376297005, 
                0.0832897946238518), conf.low = c(-0.0863742756963086, 0.106548391462203, 
                                                  -0.118361588481458, -0.0116104941083117, 0.0733361726767399, 
                                                  -0.053711285215052, -0.055059635814747, -0.0213701352922267, 
                                                  -0.0989508387655239, -0.0199225869326405, -0.0380252173646746, 
                                                  -0.040281313119597, -0.003365547364713, -0.0323906170050526, 
                                                  -0.0105198754355484, -0.131291404053158, 0.118296588464488, -0.131017153191937, 
                                                  -0.0895757264901975, 0.033413198378728), conf.high = c(0.241395572152679, 
                                                                                                         0.246105029822517, 0.12101936146781, 0.264215899351408, 0.177134674214663, 
                                                                                                         0.131018881266223, 0.0399873106610149, 0.115536535324356, 0.111787160987252, 
                                                                                                         0.0475466762034706, 0.0583720140105238, 0.0485563065056827, 0.23360877482428, 
                                                                                                         0.18259552156622, 0.0493988341078335, 0.0754273440655167, 0.27048672230845, 
                                                                                                         0.133358071977673, 0.147416001749598, 0.133166390868975), group = c("Country 1", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "Country 2", "Country 3", "Country 4", "Average", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", "Country 4", "Average", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", "Country 4", "Average", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", "Country 4", "Average"
                                                                                                         ), outcome = c("Agriculture", "Agriculture", "Agriculture", "Agriculture", 
                                                                                                                        "Agriculture", "Livestock", "Livestock", "Livestock", "Livestock", 
                                                                                                                        "Livestock", "Business", "Business", "Business", "Business", 
                                                                                                                        "Business", "Wage Labor", "Wage Labor", "Wage Labor", "Wage Labor", 
                                                                                                                        "Wage Labor"), significance = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                                                                                                                                                        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                                                                                                                                                        FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
                                                                                                                                                        ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Plot
plot %>%
  mutate(country_name = factor(country_name, 
                               levels = c("Average", "Country 4", "Country 3", "Country 2", "Country 1"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = country_name, y = estimate)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black", size = .5, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_pointrange(
    aes(
      fill = significance,
      ymin = conf.low,
      ymax = conf.high
    ),
    size = .5,
    shape = 23, 
    stroke = 1
  ) +
  labs(
    x = NULL,
    y = "Effect size in standard deviations"
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black")) +
  facet_grid(outcome ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 13) +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.y.left = element_text(face = "bold", angle = 0, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
    panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm"),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  )

This results in the following plot:

Overall it is okay, but I want to make it more similar to the plot below:

This translates to:

A horizontal line above each display outcome (Agriculture, Livestock, Business and Wage Labor) that has the same length as the x-axis:
country_name displayed at the right of every geom_pointrange


Here is one possible option which drops the axis and strip texts and instead uses two geom_label to add the annotations for the panel and the categories. Additonally I use a geom_hline to add the desired horizontal lines. Finally note that I dropped the coord_flip and instead swapped x and y.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

# Plot
plot %>%
  mutate(country_name = factor(country_name,
    levels = c("Average", "Country 4", "Country 3", "Country 2", "Country 1")
  )) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = country_name, x = estimate)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "black", linewidth = .5, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = Inf, color = "black", linewidth = .5, linetype = "solid") +
  geom_pointrange(
    aes(
      fill = significance,
      xmin = conf.low,
      xmax = conf.high
    ),
    size = .5,
    shape = 23,
    stroke = 1
  ) +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      x = conf.low,
      label = country_name
    ),
    hjust = 1,
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = ~ dplyr::distinct(.x, outcome),
    aes(
      x = -Inf,
      y = Inf,
      label = outcome
    ),
    hjust = 0,
    vjust = 1,
    fill = NA,
    fontface = "bold",
    label.size = 0
  ) +
  labs(
    y = NULL,
    x = "Effect size in standard deviations"
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, .2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black")) +
  facet_grid(outcome ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 13) +
  theme(
    strip.text.y.left = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm")
  )


